# Morphism from Automorphism group of stable curve to automorphism group of its dual graph surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

I currently study the strata of the moduli stack of algebraic curves and have understood, that for a stable curve with markings $p_1, \dots, p_n$ there is a morphism of groups $Aut(C, p_1, \dots, p_n) \to Aut(\Gamma)$, where $\Gamma$ is the associated stable graph. I also see, that because of automorphisms of the connected components of the normalisation that are not "seen" by the graph, in general this morphism is not injective.

But is it surjective? In all the examples I have considered I think it is, but I do not see a general argument to show that, so I am thankful for any hints.

Comment: Take two elliptic curves with different $j$-invariants and glue them at the marked points to obtain a stable curve $C$ (its moduli point lies in the boundary divisor $\Delta_1 \subset \overline{M}_2$). The dual graph $\Gamma_C$ consists of two vertices connected by a single edge, each vertex labeled with a $1$. Under any (I think) reasonable definition of automorphism of a decorated graph, we get an automorphism of $\Gamma$ by swapping the two vertices. Since the two elliptic curves we started with have different $j$-invariants, interchanging the curves does not give an automorphism of $C$.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. So ist it true, as every smooth curve of genus 0 is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, that this morphism is surjective, if it is restricted to those curves where every connected component of the normalisation has genus 0?